# Adding randomization to numpy function array_split

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, split

Let's propose that we have an array `arr`
and we want to divide the array into `pieces` saving the order of elements.
It can be easily done using `np.array_split`:

```
import numpy
arr = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
pieces = 3
np.array_split(arr,pieces)
>>> [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7, 8])]
```

If `arr.size % pieces != 0` the output of `np.array_split` will be uneven:

```
arr = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
pieces = 3
np.array_split(arr,pieces)
>>> [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7])]
```

I am wondering what is the best way to add randomization to the procedure to get the following outputs with equal probability:

```
>>> [array([0, 1]), array([2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7])]
>>> [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7])]
>>> [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7])]
```

I am interested in generalized solution which will also work for other combinations of array size and number of pieces, for example:

```
arr = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
pieces = 6
```

Comment: You can give `array_split` a list of indices instead of just one number.  Then it's  up to you to figure out the different splits, e.g. `np.array_split(x,[2,5])`  `[3,5]`, `[3,6]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def random_arr_split(arr, n):
    # NumPy doc: For an array of length l that should be split into n sections,
    # it returns l % n sub-arrays of size l//n + 1 and the rest of size l//n
    piece_lens = [arr.size // n + 1] * (arr.size % n) + [arr.size // n] * (n - arr.size % n)
    piece_lens_shuffled = np.random.permutation(piece_lens)
    
    # drop the last element, which is the end of the array
    # otherwise getting an empty array at the end
    split_indices = np.cumsum(piece_lens_shuffled)[:-1]
    return np.array_split(arr, split_indices)
```